# Missing compiled JavaScript after .NET publish

Tags: angular, .net-core, publish

I have a .net core with Angular app.  Using Visual studio on MAC, I published to a folder.
In the terminal I cd to the publish folder and ran `dotnet mysite.dll`
when my site come's up, it is stuck with a 'Loading...' message and the dev tools shows 404 errors for all of the compiled javascript files and css resources ex

```
runtime.8c6c71ef3bff0014.js:1 (not found)
styles.313a53c23843a233.css:1 (not found)
```

What might i be doing wrong?  What should I check?  I have the same issue when I try to publish to Azure.

Answer (score 0):

Silly me - I had a base href set in the angular.json file due to early deployment work in an IIS environment.  The files were being look for at the wrong path.